# Parsing a comma delimited string from serial monitor (AtMega2560 wifi built-in)

Tags: arduino

(This is with Arduino)
In the past I had some issues with the AtMega2560 with wifi built-in, but now I've got it somewhat working. I have a string sent from the Esp module separated by commas of individual temperature sensor readings from Thingspeak. This is then picked up by the AtMega over serial monitor and defined as a variable. How can I parse the data using commas so I can assign them to individual variables?

Help would be much appreciated.

Please see below for code and outputs.

ESP Module

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "ThingSpeak.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char ssid[] = "Beep";  // your network SSID (name)
const char pass[] = "Bap";   // your network password


WiFiClient  client;

//---------Channel Details---------//
unsigned long counterChannelNumber1 = 0000000;            // Channel ID (Current)
unsigned long counterChannelNumber2 = 0000000;            // Channel ID (Current)
unsigned long counterChannelNumber3 = 0000000;            // Channel ID (Current)
const char * myCounterReadAPIKey1 = "REPLACEME"; // Read API Key (Needs to be changed)
const char * myCounterReadAPIKey2 = "REPLACEME"; // Read API Key (Needs to be changed)
const char * myCounterReadAPIKey3 = "REPLACEME"; // Read API Key (Needs to be changed)
const int FieldNumber1 = 1;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber2 = 2;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber3 = 3;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber4 = 4;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber5 = 5;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber6 = 6;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber7 = 7;  // The field you wish to read
const int FieldNumber8 = 8;  // The field you wish to read
//-------------------------------//
 
void setup()   {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);
      Serial.println("[ON]");

}
 
 
void loop() {
  //----------------- Network -----------------//
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(ssid);
    Serial.println(" ....");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
      delay(5000);
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to Wi-Fi Succesfully.");
  }

  //----------------- Room1 -----------------//  
  long Room1 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber1, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  int statusCode;
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room1 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room2 -----------------//  
  long Room2 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber2, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room2 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room3 -----------------//  
  long Room3 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber3, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room3 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room4 -----------------//  
  long Room4 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber4, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room4 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room5 -----------------//  
  long Room5 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber5, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room5 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room6 -----------------//  
  long Room6 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber6, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room6 -----------------//  

  //----------------- Room7 -----------------//  
  long Room7 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber7, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room7 -----------------// 
   
  //----------------- Room8 -----------------//  
  long Room8 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(counterChannelNumber1, FieldNumber8, myCounterReadAPIKey1);
  statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();
  if (statusCode == 200)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Unable to read channel / No internet connection");
  }
  //----------------- End of Room8 -----------------//  
  Serial.print(Room1);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room2);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room3);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room5);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room6);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room7);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Room8);
  Serial.print(",\n");
  delay(10000);
}
```

AtMega2560

```
char *strings[8]; // an array of pointers to the pieces of the above array after strtok()
char *ptr = NULL;
float room1t, room2t, room3t, room4t, room5t, room6t, room7t, room8t;
String inString;
char raw;
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial3.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
   while (Serial3.available()) {
   raw = Serial3.read();
   Serial.write(raw);
   inString += raw;
   } 
}
```

Output

Connected to Wi-Fi Succesfully.

23,23,22,23,23,23,22,23,

23,23,22,23,23,23,22,23,

23,23,22,23,23,23,22,23,

23,23,22,23,23,23,22,23,

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/arduino/arduino-parse-string/

Answer (score -1):

I would begin with

```
Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

now you are sure that the next thing serial.read() would return is the start of a new line.
Next step is to use a loop of

```
int values [8]; 
for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
  values[i] = toInt(Serial.readStringUntil(','));
}
```